# Java Server not receiving messages from C Client via UDP

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a `C` client which uses `UDP` to send packets to my PC's `IP address`. Below is the function used to initialize the `socket`:

```
void log_init(const char *ipString) {
    log_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (log_socket < 0)
        return;

    struct sockaddr_in connect_addr;
    memset(&connect_addr, 0, sizeof(connect_addr));
    connect_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connect_addr.sin_port = 4405;
    inet_aton(ipString, &connect_addr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(log_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &connect_addr, sizeof(connect_addr)) < 0) {
        socketclose(log_socket);
        log_socket = -1;
    }
}
```

Here is the sending code:

```
void log_print(const char *str) {
    // socket is always 0 initially as it is in the BSS
    if (log_socket < 0) {
        return;
    }

    int len = strlen(str);
    int ret;
    while (len > 0) {
        int block = len < 1400 ? len : 1400; // take max 1400 bytes per UDP packet
        ret = send(log_socket, str, block, 0);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;

        len -= ret;
        str += ret;
    }
}
```

In `Java`, I want to receive those messages but they never arrive, it's always stuck on [`receive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)):

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class UDPServer
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Binding...");
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(4405);
        System.out.println("Binded!");
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1400];

        while (true)
        {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            System.out.println("Receiving...");
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("Received: " + sentence);
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, a `C` server on the same machine as the Java server works just fine and indeed receives the messages. The `socket` initialization and receive functions are below:

```
int NetInit()
{
    if(sock_id >= 0)
        return sock_id;

#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        return -1;
#endif
    //Get a socket
    if((sock_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP)) == -1)
        return -1;

#ifdef WIN32
    u_long mode = 1;
    ioctlsocket(sock_id, FIONBIO, &mode);
#else
    int flags = fcntl(sock_id, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(sock_id, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
#endif

    return sock_id;
}

int NetRead(void *buffer, unsigned int buf_len)
{
    if(sock_id < 0)
        return sock_id;

    fd_set fdsRead;
    FD_ZERO(&fdsRead);
    FD_SET(sock_id, &fdsRead);

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 10000;

    if(select(sock_id + 1, &fdsRead, NULL, NULL, &tv) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    int len = sizeof(servaddr);

    return recvfrom(sock_id,buffer, buf_len, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &len);
}
```

How do I get receiving messages to work with `Java`?

Comment: Is your C client on the same network or different? The problem might not necessarily be with the code. You may need to look into hole punching for this, as the incoming UDP packets are blocked by the firewall. You'll need to make a way to have them enter the network.

Comment: It's on the same network. The UDP packets are received with a C server but not with a Java server on the same machine which is odd since a TCP connection works with Java but not UDP.